# How can we insert custom performance counter data from Application Insights Java SDK to Cloud Services

Tags: java, azure, performancecounter, azure-application-insights

I want to insert the custom performance counter and performance counter data through Azure Application Insights SDK to Cloud Services, Virtual Machines performance counters.

How can we use Application Insights SDK to add performance counter data to performance counters for virtual machines. Can we do this using Application Insights?

Comment: There is a sample of Application Insights for Java which you can refer to, please see https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/tree/master/samples.

Answer (score 0):

See in [Customize performance counter collection](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-java-get-started/).

For example, for JMX PC you can update ApplicatonInsights.xml with):

```
<PerformanceCounters>
  <Jmx>
    <Add objectName="java.lang:type=ClassLoading" attribute="TotalLoadedClassCount" displayName="Loaded Class Count"/>
  </Jmx>
</PerformanceCounters>
```

For exmaple, for Windows PC you can update ApplicatonInsights.xml with:

```
<PerformanceCounters>
  <Windows>
    <Add displayName="Process User Time" categoryName="Process" counterName="%User Time" instanceName="__SELF__" />
  </Windows>
</PerformanceCounters>
```

You can read the parameters description in the article.

Comment: Thank you for the information. This is related to getting the performance counter data from Azure. Can we send the Metrics data to all this performance counters though Application Insights? I need to add custom performance counter which will add as we can add custom performance counters for role in cloud services, so that it will be available for the auto-scaling of Cloud Services.

Comment: If I understand you correctly,the bottom line is that you want to use AI performance counters metrics for the cloud service auto-scaling?

Comment: Yes, Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Well, I'm familiar with [Autoscaling Application Block for c#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh680892(v=pandp.50).aspx), but I'm pretty sure that there's no java porting for this. Maybe [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/best-practices-auto-scaling/) could help, using REST API.